# Do Cached History Pages Execute Their Java On Reload?

Tags: java, cookies, cgi

Also, do they somehow return cookie values to the value current when they were saved? If so, how can I stop this happening?  I want the cookie value as modified by later screens to be used when the cached history page is reloaded and the user uses that screen to progress forward. Special relevance to quizzes and user attempting to resubmit answers to previous questions, to get a better score.

Comment: `user attempting to resubmit answers to previous questions` -> don't use a cookie. Use the backing session to store relevant data. As cookies are client side. The client can modify the values

Comment: @Kenneth Clark, Note that they could still clear the cookies and start anew. How can you prevent a person from taking a quiz twice is a very difficult problem, and the solution depends on the specific. For example, you could prevent an account from taking the quiz twice, but that doesn't help if anyone can sign up for an account for free. etc.

Comment: @John Jenkins, Java or JavaScript? Either way, it's easy to test, and you should do that.

Comment: Re "*If so, how can I stop this happening?*", You can't stop the user from running code on their own computer.

Comment: You also can't prevent a user from changing data on their computer. Storing server-encrypted on the client limits how the user can change it, but they can still 1) delete the data (which would equate starting the quiz anew if no data is stored on the server), and 2) revert the data to an earlier state (which would equate undoing one or more answers). The state must be stored on the server to avoid these problems. (Though, as mentioned above, this is not sufficient solution in of itself.)

Comment: As suggested by replies, the client-side cookie got too messy to handle.  I rearranged the whole thing to use a pseudo-cookie on the server side.  Just another tiny addition to the server workload; should I loose sleep over that?